# thermodynamics - piston problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

I am struggling to solve this problem and need some help.

Consider cylindrical container with volume V. The container is divided in half by a movable piston that conducts heat. Both parts of container are filled with ideal gas with molar heat capacity:
$$
c_{v} = \frac{3}{2}R.
$$
Given parameters of the gas in the left part are:
$$
p_{0}, T_{0}, \frac{1}{2}V,
$$
right part:
$$
3p_{0}, T_{0},\frac{1}{2}V.
$$
Ignore the friction between a piston and the walls of the container.

Find parameters (V, T, p) for both sides when system achieves equilibrium.

I really don't get these piston problems. I'd be greatful for any info about a book/script where the topic is fully covered.

I tried to do it like this:

Equation of state for left side for initial state:

$$
\frac{1}{2}p_{0}V = n_{L} R T_{0} \Rightarrow RT_{0} = \frac{1}{2 n_{L}}p_{0}V.
$$

Right side:
$$
\frac{3}{2}p_{0}V = n_{R}RT_{0} \Rightarrow RT_{0} = \frac{3}{2}\frac{1}{n_{R}},
$$
where subsripts L/R mean left/right side.

Equating right sides of $RT_{0}$:
$$
\frac{1}{2n_{L}}p_{0}V = \frac{3}{2}\frac{1}{n_{R}}p_{0}V \Rightarrow 3n_{L} = n_{R} = n. 
$$
Now I wrote down equations of state for system in equilibrium
(subscripts "f" mean it's final parameter):

Left:
$$
p_{f}V_{Lf} = \frac{1}{3}nRT_{f} \Rightarrow 3p_{f}V_{Lf} = nRT_{f}
$$
Right:
$$
p_{f}V_{Rf} = nRT_{f}
$$
comparing both $nRT_{f}$:
$$
3p_{f}V_{Lf} = p_{f}V_{Rf} \Rightarrow 3V_{Lf} = V_{Rf}
$$
knowing that $V = V_{Lf} + V_{Rf}$:

$V_{Lf} = \frac{1}{4}V$ and $V_{Rf} = \frac{3}{4}V$

For closed system:
$$
\Delta U_{system} = \Delta U_{L} + \Delta U_{R} = 0.
$$
For an ideal gas $\Delta U = n c_{v} \Delta T$.

So:
$$
\Delta U_{L} + \Delta U_{R} = n_{L} c_{v} (T_{f} - T_{0}) + n_{R} c_{v} (T_{f} - T_{0}) = 0, 
$$
$$
\frac{1}{3}n c_{v} (T_{f} - T_{0}) + n c_{v} (T_{f} - T_{0}) = 0.
$$
Finally, the temperature is $T_{f} = T_{0}$.

Parameters (V, T, p) after reaching equilibrium:

Left: $(\frac{1}{4}V$, $T_{0}$, $2p_{0})$.

Right: $(\frac{3}{4}V$, $T_{0}$, $2p_{0})$.

I guess that's correct.

Also anybody knows a faster way of solving this problem?

Comment: Have you considered equating the pressure on both sides of the piston? At equilibrium, there is no net force on the piston, implying that the pressure is equal on both sides.

Comment: What is the question? You don't say what you are trying to calculate.

Comment: final parameters (V, T, p) for both parts. Sorry for mistakes I was kinda frustrated by this problem :/

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying that. However, per the [site guidelines](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange), homework-type questions should show that you've made an attempt to solve the question yourself. How have you tried to solve it and what aspect in particular are you unsure about?

Comment: How much external work is done on the surroundings of the combined system (enclosed in a rigid chamber)?  How much heat is exchanged with the surroundings?  What is the change of internal energy for the combined system?

Comment: You are correct that the change in internal energy of the overall system is zero.  You also know that, for an ideal gas, the internal energy is a function only of temperature.  So, $n_LC_v(T_f-T_0)+n_RC_v(T_f-T_0)=0$. What does this give you for the final temperature?

Comment: According to your hint it's $T_{f} = T_{0}$
So plugging results to equation of state for initial and final state I got $p_{f} = 2p_{0}$

Comment: This is correct.